# Symfony Form: keep form state after form validation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

*TestController.php*

```
public function test(Request $request, Test $test): Response
{
    $response = new Response();
    $choices = $test->getChoices()->toArray();

    shuffle($choices);
    $form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, $response,  [
        'choices' => $choices,
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //...
    }

    return $this->renderForm('test.html.twig', ['form' => $form]);
}
```

*TestType.php*

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('answers', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Choice::class,
            'choices' => $options['choices'],
            //...
        ])
        //...
}

//...
```

**Question:**
How can I prevent the *$choices* option from being re-`shuffle()`d when the form is not valid?

Comment: use form events `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

Comment: And what would I do in PRE_SUBMIT?

Comment: `shuffle` gets executed on each load, so the order is random every time. If you want to keep it consistent for the same user, you can persist the order in the session and cleanup after successful submission. Although `EntityType` might give you headaches with serialized entities, in that case I'd suggest you use `ChoiceType` directly.